# Lebesgue integral of the divergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

How can I show that for an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n  $ and $F \in C_c^1(U;\mathbb{R}^n)$    $\int_U \mathbb{div}Fd\mathcal{L}^n=0$ ?

I know that for every function $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$, if $f$ and $\partial_if$ are integrable, $\int_U \partial_ifd\mathcal{L}^n=0$.

Why do I need that the function $F$ has compact support ?

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress?

Comment: The "I know that" is false without supposing compact support